# Trying to run localhost of code I've written and get a strange error connection refused and a JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, vb.net

I've been working a a project, and I seen to be getting this error in Chrome only. Chrome's blocked by our network admin but I have a script that alters the registry and takes it off a "blacklist" so it is usable, I don't see it in the company approved browser, I.E. which I guess is good, but the JavaScript error is still there; the page where it referenced that syntax error is here.

Comment: it looks like one of your templates massed up.

Comment: great, says something to do with DOCtype ? in pic?

Answer (score 0):

You have two close tags:

```
  </div>
</div>
```

for one open.

Comment: that div was part of another i believe posted entire body where that div was

Comment: Your error says you have one bad symbol at `railcarmulti...js` at line 3.

Comment: what symbol?  this is all i have <!DOCTYPE html>